# How do you use the fill handle while skipping values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

One sheet has dates in days, I want to do the average of values over weeks. For the first week, I would do:

```
=average(A1:A7)
```

The second cell has to be

```
=average(A8:A14)
```

I have years of daily data to average into weeks. How can I make the increment go up by 7 like that?

Comment: Are you filling down or across?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can use the fill handle. Select the first seven lines and *then* pull down. In earlier versions of Excel you had to release the mouse only when selecting multiples of seven. In the latest version it seems to work always.
[image]

Secondly, you can achieve compact results using the `INDIRECT` function: Use an auxiliary column to calculate the starting rows of each week and glue together the range refererence: `INDIRECT("A"&H8&":A"&H8+6)` makes `A15:A21` in this case.

[image]